# Remotely Connect to MySql from MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Does anybody know if it is currently possible to remotely connect to a MySql server from MS Access? What does one need to do to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using linked tables. Here's the MySQL documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html

Add a User DSN from the ODBC Data Source Administrator, testing the link to your MySQL database to ensure you have the server, user name and password correct.

In Access on the External Data tab select ODBC Database. Choose the Link... option. Select Machine Data Source and the name of the DSN you set up. The tables available will appear. Choose the one(s) you want and click OK.

Comment: That only works on a local connection. I want to know how to configure a remote connection to a MySql server,

Comment: No it doesn't. I just set up an ODBC user DSN to a hosted MySQL database and linked to it via Access.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about how you did this?

Comment: @Madrigone - Did you look at the details in the link provided?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer with a bit more detail. Hope you can get this working.